# Why is Apache refusing to show new pages for one directory? This is as spooky as I've seen from Apache in a while

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, vps, linode, diskmanagement

I tried to take a step back in https://serverfault.com/questions/763747/why-is-apache-not-showing-a-new-page , from an original question that was loosely as follows:

A client has a website and makes periodic requests to add a page. The website isn't even LAMP; these are static HTML files under a Linux, Apache DocumentRoot.

After his most recent submission, I went to review the update and got a 404 page. I tried various other things; I checked file ownership and permissions to ensure they were the same as other files, and the new post, or more exactly new posts in new files, are all getting a 404 page. Other VirtualHosts appear to be displaying static content more straightforwardly; updating software didn't help, or bouncing Apache, or a reboot. Furthermore, a ServerAlias subdomain is serving up the new content perfectly; it's just the main domain.

apachectl -v gives:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Nov 28 2015 14:05:48
```

uname -a gives:

```
Linux localhost 4.4.0-x86_64-linode63 #2 SMP Tue Jan 19 12:43:53 EST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas how to address? This is the oddest behavior from dead-simple Apache that I've seen in a while.

Thanks,

Comment: What's in the apache error log?